# Do App Parts have an equivalent to Web Part Connections in 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I'm looking to write an App on SharePoint 2013, and I'd like to be able to connect App Parts in the same way you can currently connect Web Parts -- through the connections menu, and ConnectionProvider / ConnectionConsumer attributes.

I can't find any examples or references to tell me whether this is possible, or whether a similar feature exists. Anyone know if this is possible, and if so, what APIs I need to know about?

An example use case; I stick two App Parts on a page; one contains a dropdown; the other contains a table. Changing the value in the dropdown changes the contents of the table.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps don't have anything like this OOB but you could implement it in many ways.
One could be using SignalR: http://signalr.net/
Create a channel and let the apps talking together.